# Problema com JPA usando Wildfly 9 e JTA

Tags: jsf, jpa, wildfly

É primeira vez que tento utilizar o JTA usando o container Wildfly e até agora não consegui executar meu código direito.
Quando publico a aplicação(start Wildfly) ele starta perfeitamente, gera a tabela e tal. Mas quando entro na tela para exibir uma lista simples ocorre um erro.

Segue abaixo a imagem da tela do erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já configurei o datasource no wildfly(tanto que ele gera a tabela no banco de daodos).

Estou utilizando o padrão dao no projeto.

Meu persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="UmariPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/UmariDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>br.com.umari.entities.Estabelecimento</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.wrap_result_sets" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Meu dao genérico:

```
package br.com.umari.dao.impl;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import br.com.umari.dao.GenericDAO;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class GenericDAOImpl<T, PK> implements GenericDAO<T, PK> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "UmariPU")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;



    public void persist(T entity) {
        System.out.println("Entrou em genericDAO");
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }

    public void marge(T entity) {
        entityManager.merge(entity);

    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        entityManager.remove(entity);
    }

    public void removeById(PK id) {
        T entity = getByID(id);
        entityManager.remove(entity);
    }

    public T getByID(PK id) {
        return (T) entityManager.find(getTypeClass(), id);
    }

    public Collection<T> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("FROM" + getTypeClass().getName()).getResultList();
    }

    public Query createQuery(String query, Object... parameters) {
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery(query);

        for (int i = 1; i < parameters.length; i++) {
            q.setParameter(i, parameters[i]);
        }
        return q;
    }

    private Class<?> getTypeClass() {
        Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                .getActualTypeArguments()[1];
        return clazz;
    }

}
```

Estou usando as seguintes dependencias(pom.xml):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.umari.erp</groupId>
    <artifactId>Umari</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

A classe EstabelecimentoMB

```
package br.com.umari.managedbeans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;

import br.com.umari.ejbs.EstabelecimentoEjb;
import br.com.umari.entities.Estabelecimento;
import br.com.umari.util.UtilErros;
import br.com.umari.util.UtilMensagens;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class EstabelecimentoMB implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2941386880795673862L;

    @Inject
    private EstabelecimentoEjb bean;

    private Estabelecimento estabelecimento;

    private List<Estabelecimento> estabelecimentos;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        estabelecimentos = (List<Estabelecimento>) bean.findAll();
        estabelecimento = new Estabelecimento();
    }

    public String cadastrar(){
        try {
            bean.persist(estabelecimento);
            estabelecimentos = (List<Estabelecimento>) bean.findAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return "";
    }

    public String atualizar(){
        try{
            bean.merge(estabelecimento);
        }catch(Exception e){
            UtilMensagens.mensagemErro(UtilErros.getMensagemErro(e));
        }

        return "";
    }

    public void excluir(){
        try {
            bean.remove(estabelecimento);
            estabelecimentos = (List<Estabelecimento>) bean.findAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            UtilMensagens.mensagemErro(UtilErros.getMensagemErro(e));
        }
    }

    public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event){
        estabelecimento = (Estabelecimento) event.getObject();
        atualizar();
        UtilMensagens.mensagemInformacao("Estabelecimento " + estabelecimento.getRazaoSocial() + " atualizado!");
    }

    public Estabelecimento getEstabelecimento() {
        return estabelecimento;
    }

    public void setEstabelecimento(Estabelecimento estabelecimento) {
        this.estabelecimento = estabelecimento;
    }

    public List<Estabelecimento> getEstabelecimentos() {
        return estabelecimentos;
    }

    public void setEstabelecimentos(List<Estabelecimento> estabelecimentos) {
        this.estabelecimentos = estabelecimentos;
    }




}
```

Tela de Debug:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código disponível no repositório: https://bitbucket.org/umari_tecnologia/erp
Fico muito grato a quem conseguir me dar uma luz...

Comment: Será que você pode postar a classe EstabelecimentoMB?

Comment: sim. Um momento.

Comment: editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Você esta tentando fazer uso do método init() que está setado como private, tente alterar para o modificador de acesso `public`.

Na classe esta sendo utilizado anotações de duas especificações, CDI e JSF, para evitar conflitos é interessante utilizar anotações ou apenas do JSF ou apenas do CDI.

No seu EstabelecimentoMB, com @Named de CDI e @RequestScoped do JSF

Para usar apenas do CDI, utilize

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
```

JSF

```
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
```

> Vou deixar algumas observações por esta utilizando JPA

Nas dependências está utilizando Hibernate 5.0, nesse caso recomendo também utilizar o [JPA 2.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final), em seu persistence.xml está com a versão JPA 2.0

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="UmariPU" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/UmariDS</jta-data-source>

        <class>br.com.umari.entities.Estabelecimento</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.wrap_result_sets" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Aproveitando, comece também a fazer uso do `<provider>` `HibernatePersistenceProvider` do pacote `org.hibernate.jpa`.

O hibernate persistence do pacote `org.hibernate.ejb` foi depreciado nessas ultimas versões do Hibernate.

> Caso ainda estiver com problema no método findAll, tente com a API
>   Criteria.

```
public List<T> findAll() {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(getTypeClass());
    Root<T> root = query.from(getTypeClass());
    CriteriaQuery<T> select = query.select(root);
    TypedQuery<T> all = manager.createQuery(select);
    return all.getResultList();
}
```

Fiz uma breve revisão nas depêndencias, adicionei o CDI e sua implementação Weld, adicionei também a API Servlet e a especificação JPA 2.1.

http://pastebin.com/4AFFChCy

Comment: Douglas, obrigado pelas observações.
Alterei o método inicial para public, mas continua dando o mesmo erro.
 @PostConstruct
 public void init(){
  estabelecimentos = (List<Estabelecimento>) bean.findAll();
  estabelecimento = new Estabelecimento();
 }

Comment: no debug ele passa dá erro juntamente na linha 45 da classe GenericDAOImp. return entityManager.createQuery("FROM" + getTypeClass().getName()).getResultList();

Comment: Editei a resposta. Entendo.

Comment: Você entende de reflection, ou está utilizando código da internet? É legal, para cada modelo, ter seu DAO especifico.

Comment: Editei a resposta de novo, tente fazer uso dessa implementação do Criteria.

Comment: fiz as alterações, mas sem sucesso...

Comment: se quiser ver o código completo tá no repositório: https://bitbucket.org/umari_tecnologia/erp

Comment: Mesma exception?

Comment: dessa vez apareceu em português:

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: Um erro ocorreu ao realizar a injeção de recurso no bean gerenciado estabelecimentoMB

Comment: é como se na classe GenericDAOImpl a variáveis entityManager estivesse vindo nula...

Comment: coloquei na pergunta minha tela de debug que chega até a classe GenericDAOImpl

Comment: Editei novamente a resposta, tente novamente com essas dependências.

Comment: copiei as referencias, mas o mesmo erro está correndo.

Comment: Aproveita e faz um commit e push de todas modificações feitas após, para quem for ajudar, ter uma ideia.

Comment: Caso ninguem conseguir encontrar o problema, recomendo que tenha uma classe DAO diretamente com as implementações sem usar o GenericDAO e interfaces que não representam nada, apenas forçam a implementação do CRUD.